# Dynamically Loading a Movie Clip AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to add a movie clip to the stage dynamically.  In the library of the main .fla I have a movie clip called "menuBar". I have a class called menuBar.as with the following code:

```
package
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;


    public class menuBar extends MovieClip
    {


        public function menuBar()
        {
            var menuBar:MovieClip = new MovieClip  ;
            stage.addChild(menuBar);
            menuBar.x = 319.9;
            menuBar.y = 10.4;
        }
    }

}
```

The class path is set correctly, but I'm stuck at this point.  I don't know how to get the movie clip onto the stage.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the library you have to go to the properties of your clip menuBar and export it for actionscript, just check the corresponding case, in class name field enter MenuBar for exemple. Check the export in frame 1 option too. After that, anywhere in your code you can create a MenuBar with this code:

```
var myMenuBar:MenuBar = new MenuBar();
addChild( myMenuBar );
```

if you enter as class name MyOtherItem you could create it with this code:

```
var myItem:MyOtherItem = new MyOtherItem();
addChild( myItem );
```

Hope this helps

PS: try using capital letter for first letter of class names and lowercase letter for first name of variables name it's more clear for everyone. (ex: MyClassName, myVarName)

Answer (score 0):

You should do the other way. You are trying to make `menuBar` class to add itself to stage, but the stage is only known to Main, not `menuBar`. You should declare a variable in the `Main` class, on the timeline or elsewhere, and then you add that one to stage.

```
// timeline code. Put this in Main
var menubar:menuBar=new menuBar(); // declare
menubar.x=320;
menubar.y=10;  // position
addChild(menubar);  // add
```

The `menuBar` constructor should remain empty, as you are apparently designing your menu bar in the Flash CSx editor.

Also note that you might not need to add your menu bar to stage, you can easily just add it to the main class `addChild(menubar)` instead of `stage.addChild(menubar)`.